# I would like to repeat two sets of characters to achieve a form

Tags: php, repeat

I would like to achieve this form:

```
---*---
--***--
-*****-
*******
```

So far, i've tried it like this:

```
    $linii = 7;

    for($i=0; $i<=$linii; $i+=2) {
        echo str_repeat("*", $i)."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: A form? What kind of form...

Comment: for one your index for the loop should probably start at 1... secondly you should probably do your own homework or you aren't going to learn anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. First, your loop counter needs to start at `1`, for one star to be printed. From then on, think of `$i` as the number of stars to print on the current line (which you then increment by 2, which is good).

Then, you just need to do the math to figure out how many dashes to print before (and after) each set of stars are printed. It is a simple calculation: We know that there can be at most 7 characters on a line, and we know how many stars are on the current line, so we do:

```
dashes_for_this_line = max_chars_per_line - num_stars_on_this_line;
```

However, we need to print half on one side of the stars, and half on the other side, so we divide that number by two.

That, in PHP, looks like (note I've changed your variable names to make it more readable):

```
$max_chars = 7;

for($num_stars = 1; $num_stars <= $max_chars; $num_stars += 2) {
    $dashes = ($max_chars - $num_stars) / 2;
    echo str_repeat('-', $dashes);    // Print L dashes
    echo str_repeat('*', $num_stars); // Print starts
    echo str_repeat('-', $dashes);    // Print R dashes
    echo '<br />';
}
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://3v4l.org/Ze1s6), where we get as output:

```
---*--- 
--***-- 
-*****- 
*******
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you opened my mind with this.